# いつか日本に行きます。/ 五日日本に行きます。

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent, homonyms

Do these two sentences have the same sound? (The romanji are the same, but I am not sure about the stress).

1. いつか日本に行きます。(I will go to Japan someday.)
2. 五日日本に行きます。(I'm going to Japan on the 5th.)

How can we tell one from the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are different in pitch accent.

> - [いつか]{HLL}日本に行きます。 someday
> - [いつか]{LHH}日本に行きます。 on the 5th

You can check [Google Translate's synthesized voice](https://translate.google.co.jp/?hl=ja#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%0A%E4%BA%94%E6%97%A5%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82), which sounds fine enough to me.

Comment: Thank you so much!. By the way, how do you type the stress symbol in StackExchange (and in other settings, such as Google Doc)?  That would be a useful tool for me.

Comment: @leeyuiwah I used a markdown extension enabled only on this site. See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/5010